# Reproducing Google image viewer with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to simulate Google image preview in my project. I think I'm almost there but there are couple of things I struggle to implement.

So the image viewer should do the following:

1. Clicking a thumbnail will open up a preview panel right
   underneath and close other preview panel that was from other row.
   Closing other panel and opening current panel need slide transition.
2. Clicking the same thumbnail will close the preview panel.
3. Clicking "X" will also close the preview panel.
4. Opening another thumbnail that is from the same row won't do any open/close action and will just swap contents.

My accomplishment so far is:

1. is working partially - because it will only slideDown() for the
   first preview panel and won't open/close with slide transition
   anymore. And I'm not sure how other panel gets closed - I don't have any implementation for this yet.
2. I can't make this work with all other conditions together. I've tried to use id of the triggered thumbnail and assign that id to the preview panel, then if they are match, close the preview panel but it will open/close at the same time which isn't the click toggle I'm after.
3. works ok.
4. works ok although I'm not 100% sure about my approach with oldIndex.

This is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/3fc1jgog/4/) for you to play with containing the following script.

```
$.videoWatch = function(element) {
  this.$element = $(element);
  this.init();
};
var oldIndex = -1;

$.videoWatch.prototype = {

  init: function() {

    this.$openLinks = this.$element.find(".open");
    this.$closeLinks = this.$element.find(".close");
    this.open();
    this.close();
  },

  _getContent: function(element) {
    var $parent = element.parent(),
      title = $parent.data('title');

    return {
      title: title
    }
  },

  open: function() {
    var self = this;

    self.$openLinks.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var $a = $(this),
        content = self._getContent($a),
        $li = $a.parents("li"),
        $title = $(".title");

      $title.text(content.title);

      $li.append($(".preview"));

      var $preview = $li.find(".preview");

      if (!($li.index() == oldIndex)) {
        $preview.slideDown('fast');
        oldIndex = $li.index();
      }
    });
  },
  close: function() {
    this.$closeLinks.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().slideUp('fast');
            oldIndex = -1;
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  var watch = new $.videoWatch("ul");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Your appending and sliding code :

```
if (!($li.index() == oldIndex)) {
    $(".preview").slideUp('fast', function(){
        $li.append($(".preview"));

      var $preview = $li.find(".preview");
      $preview.slideDown('fast');
      oldIndex = $li.index();
    });
} else {
    $li.append($(".preview"));   
}
```

2 - You can store current thumb id and check if it's open before doing anything and if it is, close it

```
if (curID == $(this).parent().attr("id")) {
    $(".preview").slideUp('fast');
    oldIndex = -1;
    curID = "";
    return false;
} else {
    curID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3fc1jgog/10/)

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I learned to utilise anonymous function in slideUp() argument and simply returning false it's it's the same thumb id. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

nice demo, but I'm not sure what your questions are. as you've said you're expectations are unclear for how to accomplish #1 and #2

please see 
https://jsfiddle.net/mouseoctopus/7ryfLu68/
for working demo

to accomplish #1, rehide the first preview before display

```
 if (!($li.index() == oldIndex)) {
     $preview.hide(); // add this line
     $preview.slideDown('fast');
```

to accomplish #2, unsure how to do without hax, had to store figure id and hide when the same one was clicked and then reshow when id is different

```
  else{
    var figureId = $a.parent()[0].id; 
    if  ( oldFigureId == figureId ){
      $preview.slideUp('fast');
      oldFigureId = -1;
    }else{
      $preview.slideDown('fast');
      oldFigureId = figureId;
    }

  }
```

I'm not sure about the hax either with the oldIndex, oldFigureId, etc. its not clean.

Comment: It's very close to my expected outcome. The other answer was slightly more complete with the open/close transition from different rows. Thank you for your help.